# Capture what is under my Canvas as part of the Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I'm trying to do is include what is under my canvas object in the page as part of the image when I saved what is inside the canvas.

I have an application that creates a canvas and lets you draw with the mouse on it. This drawing functionality is in place so you could draw on a page as if they were notes, so after I can save the image or page with the "notes" I draw on it.

So far I'm able to save what is drown in the canvas but because the background is not part of the canvas I can't get to save it together. I tried experimenting with html2canvas.js but it doesn't work in my case because it takes the DOM object an redraw them into the canvas, it doesn't take just what is under the canvas to be part if the final image.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this, or somehow capture the pixels in that area and redraw them as part of the canvas when I'm creating it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can't without using a library like HTML2Canvas, it would be a security flaw if you could. You can go read the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468897/use-html5-canvas-to-capture-part-of-a-web-page?rq=1 if you want more explanation. I don't think telling you "you can't" is much of an answer, so I've left a comment.

Comment: If "you can't" is genuinely the answer, I see no problem with it being submitted as an answer. Especially if you go into detail about *why* you can't. @Jhawins is right. There's no way to do this without drawing the DOM in the canvas. Why can't you do that, though?

Comment: Eh, if it weren't a duplicate it would be worth letting this become a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: Others have you covered now anyway.

Comment: I was trying to do it without the DOM because it grabs much more content of what I actually need. @AlexFord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTML2Canvas (or something like it) is the only option, but it's only part of the puzzle. To get the effect you want, you need to create another canvas to composite the output from HTML2Canvas and the drawing canvas. You'll need to offset the output of HTML2Canvas to the position of your drawing canvas, and then draw the imagedata from your drawing canvas on top of it. Then you can use the imagedata from the compositing canvas as your output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks like a pretty good work around. I'll play with it and see how it goes.

Comment: @Patrick Gunderson: Can I pick your brain for your experience with Html2Canvas...Have you had good results rendering Html5+CSS3 using Html2Canvas? Myself, I've started several small projects in the hopes that Html2Canvas would work the magic and it's results just weren't close enough :-/  I've had better success sending the html+CSS to the server and having it rendered using a headless browser.

Comment: I've also had better luck sending the info back to the server to a headless browser. I don't think any HTML2Canvas-like lib is going to get you where you ultimately want to be.

Comment: You could also make a browser extension to capture the page, but that's a hurdle for many users.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a duplicate, but I'll give you a very short answer; **you can't** (unless you do something like html2canvas, where it transposes the DOM onto a canvas element)

This is by design. If you *could* it would be a security flaw. Scripts are not allowed to create images out of arbitrary stuff on a person's screen. If you search for "html canvas security rules" you'll find more information on why this is disallowed.

Comment: Isn't it only a security concern across domains? If I serve you some content, I presumably already know what's in there without needing to capture a bitmap of it.